What size compression ring for my headset
I have a semi-integrated zero stack tapered headset that is missing the compression ring. How do I know which one to order? Are they universal? Different sizes and types? How would I measure my bike for ordering correct one?

Compression rings vary significantly in total height and must match the bearing and top cap so as not to interfere with the frame (IS) or top cup (EC).
It is sometimes not much extra to buy the complete top bearing assembly (bearing, compression ring and top cap) to save alot of wasted time and ensure it works right out of the box. This approach works best on IS and hidden cup headsets.
At the shop I save old compression rings (as well as keeping some new ones) as it is usually necessary to try several and use micro spacers to get an acceptable fit and finish when making disparate components work together.

Could you be more explicit? In which way they could interfere? How does one find out that it is happenning?

@VladimirFГероямслава If the spacing provided by the compression ring is too little, the "cone spacer" will rub the frame or top cup, giving one or all of stiff feel, insufficient bearing preload, loss of steering function. Too much and aesthetically the bike will suffer, also the bearing will lose the protection of the cone as the seal will not be correctly positioned: water ingress, dust, weather etc.

When shopping for compression rings, they usually list inner diameter (example: 1.1/8 inch)
If you know your headset sizing, just grab one that matches it.
If you don't know, you might need to drop the fork and measure with a vernier caliper.
